# Table design: Type_id column or boolean column

Tags: mysql, database-design

When having two possible type of an entity is it best to use a separate table with the types or having a boolean to specify the type.

Example:

**computers**

- id
- type_id

**computer_types** (Desktop or laptop)

- id
- name

vs

**computers**

- id
- is_laptop

Considering there could only be two types.

Answer (score 1):

it is better to use computer_types table, as in future, you might need to include tablets or anything, this approach will help your database to be changed smoothly, while if you use is_laptop, you may need to add others as well.